# How to solve URL is not recognized error in windows 10?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, command-line, environment-variables

I need to run the following command to download AWS layer.

```
$ URL=$(aws lambda get-layer-version --layer-name dev-application-connector-layer --version-number 56 --query Content.Location --output text)
    curl $URL -o layer.zip
```

When run the command it's showing an 'URL is not recognized' error.

What's the best the way to address this issue?

I have added environment variable for windows but it's not solved it yet.

Comment: can you wrapt the value in double quotes? (`"`)

Comment: after adding quotes its not working its still same

Comment: What does this have to do with environment variables? You say you "added environment variable" without telling us which env var you added or why. Also, the error is from the `curl` command and means you did not provide it a valid URL. So I can only conclude your `aws lambda` command does not output a valid URL. I would start by printing the output of that command since that value might shed some light on why it isn't outputting a URL like you expect.